# How to Display a String on a DJango Form, but still reference the model

Tags: django, django-forms

I have this form:
In this form I prepopulate the dropdown with the golfer's name. I do this by using the **str** method associated with the model

The problem I run into is this no longer has any relationship to the object. So the Form is expecting a Foreign Key, but is getting a string.

is there a way to display the sting for the form, but still keep the model's PK when I POST the form?
[image]

Comment: Try using a hidden input field for the pk and keep this as it as show the string.

`<input type='hidden' name='name' value={{pk}}>`

Comment: Ill try this. I was thinking I could overwrite the POST data before it gets to form validation, but I'm having a lot of problems with it. This might be the easy quick solution.